# Does PHP Carbon have a date adjust feature using a string like strtotime() accepts

Tags: php-carbon

To expand on the title...

I've searched around but can't find any reference to a Carbon method that would come in useful - I imagine I'm not the first to need it.

Say I need to adjust a Carbon instance but using a string as [strtotime()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) accepts. For example,

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->adjust('- 3 days');
```

Why not just use `subDays()`? In my particular situation this's not posssible. Perhaps due to a fault in the way I've written the code, or maybe not.

Either way, does Carbon have this functionality, and if not is there a good reason for it?

Comment: `DateTime::modify` takes the same formats `strtotime` would, and Carbon is just extending the native DateTime class, so …

Comment: And according to https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub, the add/sub methods should work with relative formats as well.

Comment: Yep, modify was the method I was looking for - cheers!